# How to get SQL file info with unknown connection info in C#?

Tags: c#, sql

I'm trying to make a program that gets an unknown sql file (uploaded from a button) and it'll get all info in it but i cannot know any info from the connection string, because all the connection string does is rather freeze my program or give me an error.

```
private void SQLFileUploadButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
    ofd.Filter = "SQL Files|*.sql";
    ofd.Title = "Select SQL database file";
    if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        SQLFileLocationLabel.Text = ofd.FileName;
        SQLTablesComboBox.Enabled = true;
        //In here i tried to get the sql file info but no avail
    }
}
```

Comment: What do your mean `because all the connection string does is rather freeze my program or give me an error.` do you want to get connection  from the file?

Comment: yes, i'm trying to get info from sql file and after i write a conncetion string to the connection and use connection.open() it freezes the program, cannot even clicking the exit button so i got to do it through visual studio's stop debugging button

Comment: Open up SQL Server Management Studio which comes with SQL Server.  The connection string should use the same instance of the server as the login window of SSMS.

Comment: I'm not sure what you try to do here. A .sql file is essentially a text file with SQL code. You can just read it and execute it's contents on a database. A .sql file is not a database you can connect with.